# Spring Boot Controller masks static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, spring-boot

I got the following problem. I would like to have a project using Spring Boot to provide a REST API and some static Web Pages accessing that API via Javascript. Serving static content should be possible by placing it under the `static`-directory in `src/main/resources` (or anywhere else on the classpath). But unfortunately it does not work.

I created a minimalistic example to show the problem which is available on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/alis-open-stuff/spring-boot-static-web-test). The example is the basic example project from Spring Boot, on how to serve static Web content, with a small addition.

Directly after I had generated the project it worked fine. However as soon as I added the `de.cyface.controller.TestController` I could no longer access my static content `index.html`. The TestController simply masks it off.

So my question is, how do I configure my Spring Boot project for the Controller and the static page to work together properly? The solution is probably very simple and I am simply missing some important fact, but I am really stuck here. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should make the difference between REST controllers and Static controllers.
To make your code work you only should create a new Controller called for instance 
StaticContentController like this:

```
@Controller
public class StaticContentController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Then inside src/main/resources, create the folder "templates" and add the index.html

Then if you start your server and hits http://localhost:8080/index will work

Comment: But index.html should be available under http://localhost:8080/index.html and not under `static`. The folder `static` should be the default location under Spring Boot to place static content, that is available as root resource.

Comment: @ali then you can modify the Controller value by "/" and add the RequestMapping("/index") to the get method. Not sure if you can use a html file as static resource, static should be images, css, js, pdf,..but not sure for templates. But you can try and verify it

Comment: With that setup you get `Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again.` Which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the issue. I have declared my `@RestController` as `@RestController(value="/test")`. This is wrong of course. It should be

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ...
```

So I forgot. The `@RequestMapping` annotation. *headatdesk*